# PHP - htmlspecialchars_decode not working

Tags: php

I am trying to stop a webform giving "â€“" instead of "-"

```
$time = $_POST['CBTime'] ;
$fixtime = htmlspecialchars_decode($time);
```

...

```
"Contact them on $day at $fixtime.\n".
```

Is the PHP I have

And the element of the form is

```
<select class="callback-time" id="CBTime" name="CBTime"><option value="">Time</option><option>Any time</option>
<option>9am – 11am</option>
<option>11am – 2pm</option>
<option>2pm – 5pm</option>
</select>
```

So an example of what will be outputted form is:

```
Contact them on Wednesday at 9am â€“ 11am.
```

Comment: Those are not HTML entities, it's merely you handling encodings incorrectly. [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like an encoding issue.

In *PHP* place this at the top

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

if connecting to *MySQL* place this after the connect

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

betweeen your *HTML* head tags place this

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

When saving files in the *PHP* editor, ensure they are in `UTF8` format